# Is there a tutorial on how to achieve badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

I really like badges and earning stuff. I looked at the badges page for a list of badges you can earn. Some of them seem really difficult to achieve (asking questions with score of 10 or more)

Is there a tutorial out there on how to achieve badges? I want to earn as many badges as possible.

Comment: Part of the game is figuring out the rules.

Comment: Most badges are difficult to achieve because they aren't meant to be `Participation Awards`.

Comment: You have to do the things that the badges require. Ask good questions/answers, try out site features, etc. The "tutorial" is in the badge descriptions, I don't know what you expect besides that.

Comment: Give awesome answers, ask good questions, suggest useful edits, do great reviewing and you badges will overrun you.

Comment: Also, don't be a robo-reviewer. We have too many of those already.

Comment: Yeah, took me a while to figure out that the only way to fool the clerk was to put a piece of tape near the hole in the fence, scare the cat to run through the hole, use the fur that got caught on the tape when the cat ran through the hole, dip the hair in maple syrup and then slap that under my nose. The clerk never recognized me with my fake cat-hair-maple-syrup mustache.

Comment: Funny... the OP disappeared from SO only 2 days after asking this question.  I don't think staying away is the best way "to earn as many badges as possible" :)

Answer (score 14):

Nope.  You'll just have to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Now that I think of it; perhaps we should write such a guide, and then people would actually ask good questions trying to get the badges! Of course, we kind of already have one... [Help]

Answer (score 4):

The badges page should provide a complete description of what task must be completed to earn the badge. If you feel confused as to what the actual condition is for a badge to be awarded, here at Meta would be the place for you to ask for clarification. But beyond those technical conditions for awarding a badge, there's no "walkthrough" on how to gain them - the point of the badges is to recognize people who are contributing to Stack Overflow. The idea isn't that everyone should have them all and that you should be working just for the sake of earning them - it's that as you spend time here and contribute to the community, your contributions will be recognized with badges which are a nice little bonus.

Comment: He stated in the question that he has already found the list of badges and the requirements for earning them.  He is looking for instructions/advice on how to actually accomplish them, i.e. how should you go about asking a question that gets a score of 10 or more.  The badge list won't provide that information.

Comment: I understand - I'm just emphasizing WHY that's the information that's provided, and not a GameFAQs style strategy guide.